# Power app IF statement

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I am using a Power Apps If statement.

I have four questions that must be answered "YES" in order to proceed to the next screen.

If any of them is answered "NO", then navigates to a different screen.

Using following syntax:

```
If(Dropdown2.Selected.Value="YES" ,
Dropdown2_1.Selected.Value= "YES",    
Dropdown2_2.Selected.Value= "YES", 
Dropdown2_2.Selected.Value= "YES", 
Navigate(Screen1, ScreenTransition.Fade), Navigate(Screen1_2))
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
If(And(Dropdown2.Selected.Value = "YES", Dropdown2_1.Selected.Value = "YES", Dropdown2_2.Selected.Value = "YES", Dropdown2_3.Selected.Value = "YES"), Navigate(YesScreen, ScreenTransition.Fade), Navigate(NoScreen, ScreenTransition.Fade))
```

**OR**

```
If(Or(Dropdown2.Selected.Value = "NO", Dropdown2_1.Selected.Value = "NO", Dropdown2_2.Selected.Value = "NO", Dropdown2_3.Selected.Value = "NO"), Navigate(NoScreen, ScreenTransition.Fade), Navigate(YesScreen, ScreenTransition.Fade))
```

Change the name of controls, `NoScreen` & `YesScreen` with actual name of controls & screens in your app.

**Microsoft documentations**:

1. [And, Or, and Not functions in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-logicals)
2. [If and Switch functions in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-if)

Comment: Ganesh, statement worked. As always! Thanks a million for your support!